# Push next viewcontroller from a subview

Tags: iphone, subview

Is it possible to push a viewcontroller from a subview? I have a subview of (thumbnail) images, horizontally scrolling. I want each image to be a button, and when pressed to push a view controller (of the large photos). Obviously this needs to be done from the main view in which the subview resides.

I tried just allocating the large photo view controller and pushing it, but that went kaboom.

Comment: What was the exception? Kaboom doesn't help that much :)

Comment: Did you get the parent (or the grandparent) of the subview, and used that to push the new view controller? Make sure to get the right superview, before you push the new view controller.

Comment: I didn't get the right superview, I dont know how to call the superview from the subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I suggest you have an `IBAction` method that takes care of the pushing. Wire up all of your photos to that same method, on IB or programmatically.The method would be in your Main View.

It would look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)anImageWasPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{

PhotoDetailViewController *pdvc = [[PhotoDetailViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pdvc animated:YES];
[pdvc release];

}
```

You can pass the image to the new view controller in many ways. I think the best one is to have a `@Property UIImage` that you can set before pushing it.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, altho i cant figure out to get the right superview.

Comment: What do you mean "the right superview"? There should only be one. The one where your adding all your sub-views.